# delay response in JSON data which is local machine in angular js

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-service

In my angular application 
there is function init();
which I called in starting to may javascript

then there is getMonthlyNews function which is called after init()

```
function init() {
    configService.getResponders().then(function (data) {
        apiUrl = data;
    });
}
```

which is getting some setting from JSON file in local js/ folder

```
(function(){
  app.factory("configService", ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        getResponders: function () {
            return $http.get('assets/js/service/config.json')
            .then(function (res) {
                console.log("Data " + res.data.url);                                   
                return res.data.url;
            });
        }
    };
  }]);
})();
```

json file

{
    "url":"http://localhost:6790//api/getNews/"
}

```
function getMonthlyNews() {
    var method = 'Search'
    var url = apiUrl + method;
}
```

after calling init function in js file I need to get apiUrl form json file which is on local js folder using service

to get that value I have to call

when I call init function it takes time and return value after some time later
but that time interval my function getMonthlyNews already executed with an undefined error so that I have to add a setTimeOut function like that

```
setTimeout(function () { getMonthlyNews(); }, 200);
```

so how to deal with this delay or any other idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are treating a promise wrongly. All code that assumes that the promise finishes should be in it's then function.

```
var promise;
function init() {
    promise = configService.getResponders().then(function (data) {
        apiUrl = data;
    });
}

...

function getMonthlyNews() {
    promise.then(function() {
        var method = 'Search'
        var url = apiUrl + method;
    })
}
```

getting url should be done by using the new promise.